# Iterate through values of a BehaviorSubject template Layer

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, behaviorsubject

I'm having a problem to display data which is is my BehaviorSubject. I have seen this kind of iteration of an BehaviorSubject with the asyncpipe which subscribe to the Observable

SERVICE

todo.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class TodoService {

todos$: BehaviorSubject<Todo[]> = new BehaviorSubject<Todo[]>( [] ) ;

readonly todoEndPoint = environment.endpoint + "todos"

constructor( private $http: HttpClient) {}

getAllTodos(): Observable<Todo[]>{
return this.$http.get<Todo[]>( this.todoEndPoint )
    .pipe(
      tap( val => this.todos$.next( val ))
    )
}
}
```

Compontent where i want it to use

```
export class TodoListComponent implements OnInit {

constructor( public $todo: TodoService ) {
  $todo.getAllTodos().subscribe()
}

ngOnInit() {
}

}
```

Template Layer

```
<div *ngFor="let todo of $todo.todos$ | async">
  {{ todo.text }}
</div>
```

---------------------------------------------------------- EDIT ------------------------------------------------------------------
I´m getting this Error

> ERROR Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

Is there any possibility to iterate through the data stream of the BehaviorSubject

---------------------------------------------------------- SOLUTION ---------------------------------------------------------
My backend sent a Object of Array´s not Array´s. That was the issue changed now the response to Arrays

Comment: *I having a problem*: **what** is the problem? Be precise. What do you expect to happen, and what happens instead?

Comment: Added the Error Message. I want to subscribe to my BehvairoSubject in the template layer and iterate through the data stream.

Comment: Look at the network tab of your browser dev tools, and paste the response you get from the request to the todoEndpoint. I bet it's not an array of Todo as you claim it is, but it's an object instead.

Comment: You are right, it is an Object which has Arrays in it. Changed now the Backend, so it´s responding with Array´s not with an Object that has Arrays in it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In service:

```
@Injectable()
export class TodoService {

readonly todoEndPoint = environment.endpoint + "todos"

constructor( private $http: HttpClient) {}

getAllTodos(): Observable<Todo[]>{
return this.$http.get<Todo[]>( this.todoEndPoint );
}
}
```

In component:

```
export class TodoListComponent implements OnInit {

public todoitems$: Observable<Todo[]>;

constructor( private $todo: TodoService ) {
}

ngOnInit() {
     this.todoitems$ = this.$todo.getAllTodos();
}

}
```

In Template:

```
<div *ngFor="let todo of todoitems$ | async">
  {{ todo.text }}
</div>
```

Comment: That doesn´t work for me its given me the same Error. Also I want to use the BehaviorSubject

Comment: Make sure your HTTP returns array ob objects. NgFor will work only Arrays and itterable. If your HTTP returns object. You need to convert object to array before calling async. In Angular 6.1, NgFor support KeyValue pipe.

Answer (score 0):

TS:

service:

```
getAllTodos(): Observable<Todo[]>{
return this.$http.get<Todo[]>( this.todoEndPoint );
}
```

component:

```
export class TodoListComponent implements OnInit {

//todos as observable.
public todos: Observable<Todo[]>;

constructor( private $todo: TodoService ) {
}

ngOnInit() {
     this.todos = this.$todo.getAllTodos();
}

}
```

HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let todo of todos | async">
  {{ todo.text }}
</div>
```

Comment: That doesn´t work for me its given me the same Error. Also I want to use the BehaviorSubject